# Cocoapods does not recognise static constants in a struct in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am uploading my lib to Cocoapods. After all is written, I ran `pod spec lint DWActionsMenu.podspec` and ran into a weird error.

Here is the key line of my podspec:

```
s.source_files  = 'DWActionsMenu/*'
```

But when `pod spec lint DWActionsMenu.podspec` is run, the following error occurs:

```
-> DWActionsMenu (1.0.1)
- ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  DWActionsMenu/DWActionsMenu/DWActionButton.swift
:44:51: error: use of unresolved identifier 'Constants'
```

The situation is, my code runs **correctly** on my phone. `Constants` is a struct defined in `ActionsMenuConstants.swift` file.

This is what `ActionsMenuConstants.swift` looks like:

```
struct Constants{
    static let kBUTTONSIZE : CGFloat = 44.0
    //......
    static let kMENUHEIGHT : CGFloat = 44.0
}
```

That's all it has.

So `pod spec lint` just simply ignored my `Constants` struct in a separate file?????

How to solve it?

Comment: Are you using the beta version of CocoaPods? Otherwise swift is still not supported. If you are this could be a bug and you should report it [here](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues) if someone hasn't already.

Comment: Yes I believe it to be a reproducible bug, have been reported. Hopefully it can be solved shortly

Comment: does it need to be public?

Comment: Yeah, I want to share it

Comment: I had to work around it by removing static tags and create a constant refers to this Constant struct to use all of my constants. I believe Cocoapods just can't recognise static var in a struct atm. I have made a ticket in their repo. After this workaround, I have encountered into another issue with -Xlinker. Anyway, I think CocoaPods isn't quite integrated to Swift yet....

Comment: Could u able to find solution @donkey